# value of specific group attributes of product

Tags: product, attributes, attribute-set

in manage attributes set say default i created a group say "my custom group" now i want to get value of all attributes under this group for current product how can i do this?..

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->load($this->getProduct()->getId());
                   echo "<pre>";
                   print_r($attributeValue->getData());
                   echo "</pre>";
```

show all attributes for product

Answer (score 2):

If you know the product attribute group id then you can load all the attributes that are in this group via the following code snippet (`$group_id` is the group id):

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
    ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group_id)
    ->checkConfigurableProducts();
```

This should give you a collection of all the attributes in this group. You can then loop through this collection and set a value against the product for each attribute.

There is probably a smart way to use this collection and set values for a product without looping through the collection but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not fetch the Attributes values as per group.

Magento Follow the **`EAV Model`**.

So if you want to access the value form any Custom attribute value for that product then you have to follow the Magento Standard Way as below.

**`Syntax`**

> $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($Id);

Once you write above line the it will fetch all data for that product. Now you want to fetch the value of any attributes like name, color or any other attributes then use below code.

> $product->getData('Attribute Code');

Or

> $product->getName();

This way you can access the details of any attributes.